# Python: Files assigned variable path not printing or editing

Tags: python

I have most of the program done. The last part of this program needs to open the file in append mode> Add 2 names > close file. Then, it has to open file in read mode> print contents> close file.

The file path has been assigned to a variable.
I keep getting the below error. (code is below that)
I don't know what to do to fix this

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\gorri\Desktop\College Work\CPT180_ShellScripting\Assignments\Programs\workWithFiles2.py", line 34, in 
cat_files = open(cat_files, 'a')
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import os.path

path_E = Path('E:/CPT180Stuff')
os.chdir(path_E)  

cat_files = (path_E / 'pets' / 'cats' / 'catnames.txt')

    #opens catnames file to append end and add names.
    cat_files = open(cat_files, 'a')
    cat_files.write('Princess\nFreya\n')
    cat_files.close()
    cat_files = open(cat_files, 'r')
    cat_files = cat_files.read()
    print(cat_files)
    cat_files.close()
```

Comment: First you had `cat_files` as a string, then you reassigned it to an open file. Use separate variables.

Answer (score 1):

In your current code, you are first assigning `cat_files` to the file name, but then in this line:

```
cat_files = open(cat_files, 'r')
```

You are now assigning `cat_files` to a **file handle**, which is not a string. This is why the next statement fails: **it is expecting the filename string,  not the file handle**. You should use a different variable name for the handle, e.g.:

```
#opens catnames file to append end and add names.
f = open(cat_files, 'a')
f.write('Princess\nFreya\n')
f.close()
f = open(cat_files, 'r')
f = f.read()
print(f)
f.close()
```